# Linechart x-axis value reapiting in library MPAndroidchart

Tags: java, android

I have a problem when i set value from sqlite to x-axis label.
[this is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RNZL.png)
And my code of X-axis forrmated is

```
Axis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            String selectQueryz = "SELECT  * FROM table_palembang";
            db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
            SQLiteDatabase dbz = db.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursorz = dbz.rawQuery(selectQueryz, null);
            countz = cursorz.getCount();
            String[] datez = new String[countz];
            ArrayList<String> arral = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int k = 0; k < countz; k++) {
                cursorz.moveToNext();
                datez[k] = cursorz.getString(2);
                arral.add(datez[k]);
            }
            return datez[countz % arral.size()];
        }
    });
```

can anyone help me?
thanks ...

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: Show how you add data in ArrayList<Entry> for LineDataSet

Comment: check the picture, when i set value on x-axis, the value just repeating first item in array 08 Oct 2018 @VygintasB

Comment: db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase dbs = db.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursors = dbs.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
int counts = cursors.getCount();
double[] y = new double[counts];
String[] date = new String[counts];
   for(int m = 0; m < counts; m++) {
        cursors.moveToNext();
        y[m] = cursors.getDouble(1);
        date[m] = cursors.getString(2);
     }
    for (int i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {
          float val = (float) y[i];
          values.add(new Entry(i, val));
      }
@MilosLulic

Comment: `getFormattedValue` callback is used to format your values. It is called eachtime you try to format values. You set every xAxis value to the last value of db. You should set values in diffrent place. Don't forget to put DB calls to background thread too.

Comment: can you give me example code @VygintasB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ValueFormatter` is used to format your data which you set with `chart.setData()` not to set data itself.

Here is sample code how to format dates

```
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {

    private final SimpleDateFormat mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {

        long millis = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis((long) value);
        return mFormat.format(new Date(millis));
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

I just took a look that you store indices of date array to chart data. If so, you just need to return date from dates array.

```
String[] datez;
String selectQueryz = "SELECT  * FROM table_palembang";
db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase dbz = db.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursorz = dbz.rawQuery(selectQueryz, null);
countz = cursorz.getCount();
datez = new String[countz];
for (int k = 0; k < countz; k++) {
    cursorz.moveToNext();
    datez[k] = cursorz.getString(2);
}
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {

        return datez[(int) value];
    }
});
```

**P.S.** DataBase calls should be in background thread.

Comment: and how can i set db to axis label?